# Looking for company job listing script

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mysql

Our company wants to have a simple job listing and resume uploading script. We'll only have a few jobs listed at any one time. Also, they are not interested in an "online application" at this time; just a simple form to upload a resume and email the correct HR people.

Thinking that the index page will list the jobs after a short "working here is great" intro paragraph. Clicking on the job will display details in an animated display of a previously hidden DIV or similar. Clicking on Apply for this Job button will send to simple form asking name, email, and phone, with button to choose and upload resume file (to our MySQL database). Needs a form to input available positions.

The only open source solutions I've found are scripts for job boards. That isn't really what I'm looking for, I don't think.

Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the ['Very Easy To Use PHP File Upload System'](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/easy-uploader/) I've had success with it previously and it's very simple to use.